# Detecting interactive shell within ksh ENV script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

What's the preferred way to determine if a given ksh invocation is running an interactive shell?

I have some commands in an `ENV` file that I would like to skip for non-interactive ksh invocations (e.g. when executing a shell script).

I've seen suggesting ranging [from](http://sage.org/lists/sage-members-archive/1999/msg00551.html):

```
if [[ $- = *i* ]]; then
    # do interactive stuff
fi
```

...to not even sourcing `.kshrc` unless the shell is determined to be interactive using this cryptic [incantation](http://sage.org/lists/sage-members-archive/1999/msg00552.html):

```
ENVIRON=$HOME/.kshrc                                    export ENVIRON
ENV='${ENVIRON[(_$-=1)+(_=0)-(_$-!=_${-%%*i*})]}'       export ENV
```

Answer (score 5):

I have found checking the $- variable for the 'i' flag the best method in ksh.

```
if [[ $- = *i* ]]; then
    #do interactive stuff     
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

In **bash**, these two methods are often used inside `~/.bashrc`:

- Check if `stdin` is a tty:

  ```
  [ -t 0 ] || return
  ```

  or

  ```
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
      # do interactive stuff
  fi
  ```
- Check if the prompt (`$PS1`) is set:

  ```
  [ -z "$PS1" ] || return
  ```

But I don't know how to do that in ksh.

Comment: Is '-t N' definitive? Are there cases where it differs from '$- = *i*'?

Comment: `test -t 0` is for testing, whether `stdin` is a terminal. That's not the same as whether the shell is interactive. You could run a shell-script, for example, reading from tty.

Comment: @MikhailT Shell scripts generally do not source ~/.bashrc, do they?

Comment: You mean, `~/.kshrc`, @grawity. Both ksh and bash read their respective `~/.foorc` files only when they are _interactive_ shells to begin with. There is no need to check for it there. But if you do check anyway, may as well check properly...

Comment: @MikhailT You might want to inform Debian about that, because their copy of bash is compiled differently and reads .bashrc for batch SSH logins too.

Comment: All the more reason to check for interactivity _properly_.

Answer (score 0):

Its also possible to use 'tty -s':

```
The following exit values are returned:

  0        Standard input is a terminal.

  1        Standard input is not a terminal.
```

Answer (score 0):

A proper KSH shell should not invoke $ENV when running a script.  However, this has been a long present bug in Sun's `ksh88` dialect, and was actually patched late in Solaris 10.  (Quite a surprise, as Sun traditionally was very reluctant to change existing behaviour, because such fixes could break workarounds. In this case the standard prevailed.)

To prevent sun's ksh88 to read $ENV on running a script, it was common to use the `#!/bin/ksh -p` workaround, and was safe if you did not have an `/etc/suid_profile` hanging around.

However,  $- *is* a reliable indicator of an interactive shell, unless you fake it.

```
$ cat interactive.sh
echo \$- = $-
[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo interactive || echo not interactive
```

When run as a script this gives:

```
$ ksh  interactive.sh
$- = hB
not interactive
```

When we fake the `-i` flag, you get what you ask for:

```
$ ksh  -i interactive.sh
$- = imBE
interactive
```

And when sourced from an interactive shell, it will do the right thing:

```
$ . ./interactive.sh
$- = imsBEl
interactive
```